# Regex: How to trim off everything before last / in Bash function?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bash function that takes a param, runs it through JS Lint, then outputs the result into a file on the Desktop. This works so long as you're in the directory of the JS file when you run it. However if you pass the function a path it chokes. jslint is the name of my function. Examples:

```
# This works
$ jslint script.js

# This doesn't work
$ jslint ~/dev/project/js/script.js

# Neither does this
$ jslint /Users/Jesse/dev/project/js/script.js
```

In my function I need to take $1 and trim off the path when I go to output it preferably using regular expressions. See my function below:

```
function jslint {
    /usr/local/bin/node /usr/share/node-jslint/node_modules/jslint/bin/jslint.js $1 > "~/Desktop/" + $1 + "-lint.txt"
}
```

Here's am example error from a project I am working on and tried to run it on:

`-bash: /Users/Jesse/Desktop/Dropbox/dev/ourcityourstory.com/js/script.js-lint.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Re: "preferably using regular expressions": Can you explain your reason for this preference? Unless you have a strong one, it seems easier to use `"$(basename "$1")"` or `"${1##*/}"`.

Comment: Those were just examples. The error is a real-world application. They both illustrate that the issue is that the $1 is getting appended to the path that I'm outputting the lint results to which I want to appear on the desktop. If $1 is just a js file it works. But if it's a path it doesn't work because the function tries to output the result into ~/Desktop/some/non/existent/path/script.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex. Bash supports simple glob patterns for trimming prefixes/suffixes. This can be done with `${1##*/}`, which trims everything up to the last `/` from the variable.

Specifically, there are 4 variants:

1. `${var#pat}` treats `pat` as a glob and trims the shortest matching prefix from `var`.
2. `${var##pat}` treats `pat` as a glob and trims the longest matching prefix from `var`.
3. `${var%pat}` treats `pat` as a glob and trims the shortest matching suffix from `var`.
4. `${var%%pat}` treats `pat` as a glob and trims the longest matching suffix from `var`.

In your specific case, you'll probably want to say

```
function jslint {
    /usr/local/bin/node /usr/share/node-jslint/node_modules/jslint/bin/jslint.js "$1" > "~/Desktop/" + "${1##*/}" + "-lint.txt"
}
```

(I've also quoted the variable, which is necessary if the path contains spaces)

Comment: Not applicable to this specific question, but I've seen people use ${var%%pat} as a replacement for dirname and get in trouble when the variable contains no /s (dirname returns . in that case, ${var%%pat} leaves the value unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `regex` - what about `basename` which outputs the string from the last '/' of the file path parameter.

```
e.g. basename /usr/include/stdio.h  --> stdio.h
```